# How to Run Selenium python code in a online server

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have written a few Selenium (Python) webdriver scripts, and they are running fine on my system, the script outputs a few .csv files. 
Is there anyway to run those scripts in a online server in a way that saves the data of the .csv files in a online database and i don't neeed to run manually the scripts.

Comment: What do you mean by online server? One set up by yourself locally or run in the cloud like AWS, Azure, etc?

Comment: run in a cloud sorry

Comment: Well it is possible to do, the setup depends on which cloud service you'd use and you probably will have to run it in a virtual machine

Comment: can you explain me better?

Comment: It all depends if you use azure, aws, google cloud, etc. So it is hard to explain much better, but you just set up a machine on their servers to run every so often which can save the data to a cloud database or one of your own.

Comment: i want to use azure